# Can I use master's theorem for this recurrence relation?

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I solved my homework problem, I used recursion tree.

But solution says that this recurrence relation can be solved by master's theorem!

T(N) = 49T(N/25) + n^(3/2)log(n)

I solved n^(3/2) log^2(n)

But solution said n^(3/2) log(n)

I don't know why this case can use master's theorem and it is correct.

Comment: hey man, if you are still here on SO, can you tell me where you got this problem and its solution, I got the problem in Papadimitriou, but I don't have a solution manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can see that `a=49` and `b=25`.  Note that `log_b(a) ~ 1.2` and that `3/2 = 1.5`.  Hence, `log_b(a) < 3/2`.  Thus, we can see that `f(n) = n^{3/2}log(n) = Omega(n^{log_b(a) + epsilon})` for some epsilon, so that Case 3 of the master theorem applies.  Thus, the run time is

```
T(n) = Theta(f(n)) = n^{3/2}log(n)
```

*Note:* You also have to check that

```
af(n/b) <= cf(n)
```

for some constant `c`.  Of course

```
49 (n/25)^{3/2} log(n/25) <= c n^{3/2}log(n)
```

which can be checked by dividing both sides by `n^{3/2}` and then subtracting `c log(n)` from both sides which gives

```
(49/25^{3/2} - c) log n - 49/25^{3/2} log(25) <= 0
```

This is certainly true at least for `c > 49/25^{3/2}` (no need to make this tight).

Comment: does it guarantee c<1? Because I can take c>49/125?

Comment: Note that `49/25^{3/2} = 49/125 = 0.392 < 1`, so, for example, `c = 0.4` is an example of a constant `c < 1` such that the condition holds.